# How to turn off Quickboot/fastboot on HP Pavillion

Tags: system-installation, hp, bios

I want to install Ubuntu on my HP Pavillion G6. It has a Windows 8 logo, but in the BIOS, I can't disable Quickboot or Fastboot, (I can't even find it in the BIOS.) How can I turn it off?

Comment: this may be exactly what your looking for: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system/228069#228069

Answer (score 0):

If you see the quick boot option in bios but you can not select it, first try to set a user password in your bios to see if the option gets activated or not. Then if you dont need your windows 8 installation and also you dont need EFI mode just disable UEFI in your bios. I hope it gives you the option to choose legacy BIOS mode instead of UEFI mode.